# Android ORMs: Can't recognize method in annotations

Tags: java, android, android-studio, orm, dbflow

In my Android app I'm trying to implement ORM for SQLite database for existing db. I've tried to implement activeandroid and DBFlow, but Android studio shows error that it can't recognize method. Here's how it shows when I try to use DBFlow ORM and similarly for activeandroid it doesn't recognize methods in annotations. The red in below screenshot is error. It says it can't recognize method databaseName and also constant PRIMARY_KEY doesn't exist.
[image]

Here's project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's app: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:1.5.0'
    apt 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:1.5.0'
    apt 'com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:3.0.0-beta1'
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:3.0.0-beta1"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:3.0.0-beta1"
}
```

Comment: In the future, please post formatted code in the question rather than a screenshot of it.

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file and please try to sync and make project

Comment: @MustansarSaeed added build.gradle

Comment: Please try to add `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` in your app module `build.gradle` and then sync

Comment: I figured it out, silly me. I was reading from the blog and they changed the api in newer version, it seems to work now. Thanks.

Comment: DBFlow 2.2.1 is working fine without any issue, newer version has some bugs

Comment: @MustansarSaeed it seems to work now, but if I encounter some issues, I'll revert to 2.2.1. thanks for the sugesstion